# does the identity $\ln(z^n) = n\times\ln(z)$ hold for complex variables ?!

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

This was a problem in a complex textbook:

is the collection of all values of $\ln(i^2)$ the same as the collection of all values of $2\ln(i)$?

And I guess the answer is no as the first will yield the set of values $i(\pi + 2k\pi)$ while the second yields $2\ln(i) = 2(\ln(1) + (\pi/2 + 2k\pi) i) = i(\pi + 4k\pi)$ which contradicts the identity given in Dennis Zill's textbook page 182 stating that

$(iii) \ln z^n = n\ln z$.

---

Just a random thought came to my mind after writing this question.

the first identity on the same page states that $(i) \ln(z_1 z_2 ) = \ln z_1 + \ln z_2$. this and the third identity seem to be equivalent by substituting both $z_1$ and $z_2$ by $i$.
So, $$\ln(i \times i) = \ln(i) + \ln(i) = i\times(\pi/2 + 2k\pi) + i \times (\pi/2 + 2n\pi) = i \times \pi + 2s\pi$$ which is correct but this implies one of two things:

1. $\ln(i) + \ln(i) \neq 2\ln(i)$
2. $2\times \ln(i)$ is not a multiple of the multi-valued function $\ln$ but rather a sum of two instances of $\ln(i)$.

Which both seems very odd, So what am I getting wrong?!

**Edit**
n is an integer and ln is the multivalued function while Ln is the principal value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Hint:* In general the following holds for  the multivalued function $\arg z$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\arg(z^2)=\arg(z)+\arg(z)\ne 2\arg (z)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> See for instance *[this paper](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph116A/clog_11.pdf)*.

The argument $\arg (z)$ of a non-zero complex number $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is a *multi-valued* function and plays a key role in understanding the properties of the complex logarithm and power functions.

> Any number $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ can be written as
> \begin{align*}
> z=|z|e^{i\arg (z)}
> \end{align*}
> where $\arg(z)$ is a multi-valued function given by
> \begin{align*}
> \arg(z)=\mathrm{Arg}(z) + 2k\pi\qquad\qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}
> \end{align*}
> and $\mathrm{Arg}(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$ is the *[principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value)* of $\arg(z)$.

> We can consider $\arg(z)$ as the set of values
> \begin{align*}
> \arg(z)=\{\theta,\theta+2\pi,\theta-2\pi,\theta+4\pi,\theta-4\pi,\ldots\}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> with $\theta=\mathrm{Arg}(z)$. With the representation (2) in mind we consider the equation
> \begin{align*}
> \arg (z_1)=\arg (z_2)
> \end{align*}
> as equality of *sets*. We conclude
> \begin{align*}
> \arg(z)+\arg(z)&=(\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2k\pi)+(\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2l\pi)\qquad\qquad &k,l\in\mathrm{Z}\\
> &=\mathrm{Arg}(z)+\color{blue}{2} m\pi\qquad\qquad &m\in\mathrm{Z}\\
> 2\arg(z)&=2(\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2n\pi)=\mathrm{Arg}(z)+\color{blue}{4}n\pi
> \qquad\qquad &n\in\mathrm{Z}\\
> \end{align*}
> Since multiplication of complex numbers implies adding the arguments the statement (1) follows.

We are now ready to analyse $\ln(z^n)$.

> We obtain for $n\in\mathbb{N},n>1$
> \begin{align*}
> \ln(z^n)&=\underbrace{\ln(z)+\ln(z)+\cdots +\ln(z)}_n\\
> &=\left(\ln|z|+i\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2k_1\pi i\right)+\left(\ln|z|+i\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2k_2\pi i\right)\\
> &\qquad+\cdots+\left(\ln|z|+i\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2k_n\pi i\right)& k_1,\ldots,k_n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
> &=n\ln|z|+ni\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2m\pi i& m\in\mathbb{Z}\\
> n\ln(z)&=n\left(\ln|z|+i\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2k\pi i\right)\\
> &=n\ln|z|+ni\mathrm{Arg}(z)+2\color{blue}{n}k\pi i&\qquad\qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}
> \end{align*}
> We conclude the following are *not* set equalities:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\ln(z^n)=\underbrace{\ln(z)+\ln(z)+\cdots +\ln(z)}_n\ne n\ln (z)}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Why then $\log(z^{\frac{1}{n}})=\frac{1}{n}\log(z)$. Following your logic $ \log(z^{\frac{1}{n}})= \frac{1}{n} \left( \log(z) +2\pi m n \right)$. But isn't $mn$ spoil the equality of the sets. Also $\log(z^{-1})=-\log(z)$ or $\log(z^{-1})=-\left( \log(z) -2\pi m \right)$. Again the negative $-2\pi m$ looks like a problem.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: See equations (53) and (62) in the paper.

Comment: $arg(z)+arg(z)$, shouldn't that be $2Arg(z) + 2m \pi$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let us use the following symbology
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm Ln}(z) = \ln \left| z \right| + i\,{\rm Arg}\left( z \right) = \ln \left| z \right| + i\,\left( {\arg (z) + 2k\pi } \right) = \ln (z) + i2k\pi  \hfill \cr 
  \ln (z) = \ln \left| z \right| + i\arg (z) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so that ${\rm Ln}(z)$ is the *Multivalued* function and $\ln(z)$ the principal branch.

Then it is always true that
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\rm Ln}\left( {z\,w} \right) = \ln \left| {\,z\,w\,} \right| + i\,{\rm Arg}(z\,w) =   \cr 
  &  = \ln \left| {\,z\,} \right| + \ln \left| {\,w\,} \right| + i\,{\rm Arg}(z) + i\,{\rm Arg}(w) =   \cr 
  &  = \ln \left| {\,z\,} \right| + \ln \left| {\,w\,} \right| + i\,{\rm arg}(z) + i\,{\rm arg}(w) + i\,2\,\left( {k + l} \right)\,\pi  =   \cr 
  &  = \ln \left( z \right) + \ln (w) + i\,2\,k\,\pi  =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm Ln}\left( z \right) + {\rm Ln}\left( w \right) \cr} 
$$

If you **take note of the** $k$ **and** $l$ that appear in the third line, you 
will immediately notice where you went astray, and how to deal with $z^n$,
i.e.:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & {\rm Ln}\left( {z^{\,n} } \right)\quad \left| {\;0 \le n \in \mathbb Z} \right.\quad  = {\rm Ln}\left( {\prod\limits_{1 \le j\, \le \,\,n} z } \right) = n\,{\rm Ln}\left( z \right) =   \cr 
  &  = n\,\ln \left( z \right) + i\,\bigcup\limits_{1 \le j\, \le \,\,n} {\left\{ {2\,k_j \,\pi } \right\}}  = n\,\ln \left( z \right) + i\,2\,k\,\pi  \cr} 
}$$

*Answer to your comments*

The core lays on understanding the definition of ${\rm Arg}$ (in my notation).
When we write 
$$
{\rm Arg}(z) = \,{\rm arg}(z) + 2\,k\,\pi \quad \left| {\;k \in \mathbb Z} \right.
$$
we actually mean that to ${\rm arg}(z)$ we shall add  set of multiples of $2\pi$.
Then
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\rm Arg}(z\,w) = {\rm Arg}(z) + \,{\rm Arg}(w) =   \cr 
  & {\rm arg}(z) + 2\,k\,\pi  + {\rm arg}(w) + 2\,l\,\pi \quad \left| {\;k,l \in \mathbb Z} \right. \cr} 
$$
because we are not obliged to choose the same $k$ for $z$ and for $w$,
and since
$$
\left\{ {\left( {k + l} \right)\quad \left| {\;k,l \in \mathbb Z} \right.} \right\} = \left\{ {k\quad \left| {\;k \in \mathbb Z} \right.} \right\}
$$
we conclude that
$$
{\rm Arg}(z\,w) = {\rm arg}(z) + {\rm arg}(w) + 2\,k\,\pi \quad \left| {\;k \in Z} \right.
$$
That is equivalent to write
$$
z\,w = \left( {ze^{\,i2k\pi } } \right)\left( {we^{\,i2l\pi } } \right) = zwe^{\,i2k\pi } 
$$
Repeating the above we reach to $z^n$ ($n$ natural integer).

While instead, for $n=1/2$ for example, we get
$$
z^{\,1/2}  = \left( {ze^{\,i2k\pi } } \right)^{\,1/2}  = z^{\,1/2} e^{\,ik\pi }  = z^{\,1/2} e^{\,ik\pi } e^{\,i2l\pi }  = \sqrt z \,e^{\,ik\pi }  =  \pm \sqrt z \,e^{\,i2k\pi } 
$$
from which the ${\rm Arg}$ follows easily.

That means that the division by $2$ is applied to all the members of the set $ \left\{ {k\quad \left| {\;k \in \mathbb Z} \right.} \right\}$,
**differently** from the multiplication by $n$, where instead the set is composed by adding $n$ different elements.

I do know that the subject is not easy. I do not know the sources that you mention. Mine studies on the subtleties of exponentiation and log 
were on " Theory of analytic functions" - A.I. Markuševič

Comment: I think you swapped the definition of both (Ln(z) and ln(z)) and (Arg(z) and arg(z)). And I understand (and agree with) the derivation but I can't understand how it is related to $z^n$.

Comment: @OmarElawady:  Apart from symbology (I am used to capital L, A represent the "widest" one), I added for $z^n$, trying to make clear that it is **not $n2k\pi$** but the union of the sets of the single Arg's.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I find it difficult to grasp that $2*(2ki\pi) != (4ki\pi)$ as the definition of ln is $ln(z) = ln(|z|) + i * (2k\pi + Arg(z))$. Is there some reference about how to treat such multivalued functions ?

Comment: Also in a different textbook (I've just seen it know) "
Complex Variables and Applications (Brown and Churchill)". it is stated explicitly that "$log(i^2) != 2*log(i)$ because $ln(i^2) =log(-1)= (2n + 1 )\pi$ while $21og(i) = 2[ln(1)+ i(\pi/2+2n\pi)] = (4n+1)\pi$

Comment: And interestingly by the same autor in another book "Advanced engineering mathematics 6th edition". in exercise 17.6 p.47 in page in, "Determine whether the given statement is true. 1.doesn't matter. 2.$Ln(i^3) = 3Ln(i)$
3.$ln(i^3) = 3ln(i)$
and in the answers in the end of the book is 47.no;no;no"

Comment: @GCab: In general we have $\ln(z^n)\ne n\ln(z)$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: Markus, are you speaking of the "multivalued" log ?

Comment: @GCab: Yes, according  the notation given *[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)*.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: ok, we agree $arg(z)+arg(z)=2Arg(z)+2k\pi \ne 2Arg(z)+4k\pi$ (with your notation):see my addendum above. The multiples of $2\pi$ are not to be added, but treated as a union of sets.

Comment: @GCab: Adapting your notation the essence is to show that $\mathrm{Arg}(z)+\mathrm{Arg}(z)\ne 2\mathrm{Arg}(z)$ from which  $\mathrm{Ln}(z^2)\ne 2\mathrm{Ln}(z)$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a complex logarithm not as a multivalued function with values in $\Bbb C$, but as usual single-valued fnction, but with with values in $\Bbb C/2 \pi \sqrt{-1}$; image is still an abelian group, and so $\ln(z^s) = s \ln(z)$ for $s \in \Bbb C/2 \pi \sqrt{-1}$ makes sense (and true).

$\exp$ and $\ln$ can be though as single-valued and even bijective functions

$$\exp: \Bbb C/2 \pi \sqrt{-1} \to \Bbb C^*,$$ $$\ln: \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C/2 \pi \sqrt{-1} $$

which are homomorphisms of corresponding groups — additive $\Bbb C/2 \pi \sqrt{-1}$ and multiplicative $\Bbb C^*$. (if you want to obtain "usual" $e^z$ and $\ln(z)$ from these, you should precompose $\exp$ with factorization, and lift values after applying $\ln$) But when you take preimage of a point along projection $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C/2 \pi \sqrt{-1}$, it's not a subgroup, but a coset, so multiplying by $s$ in $\Bbb C$ will get you wrong answer; you should first multiply in factor, and then lift values.